# Does the current in a resistor depend on the speed of electrons?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, electrons, electric-current, electrical-resistance

If the speed of electrons in resistor is slow, then will the current be slow and if the speed of electrons is fast, then will the current be fast? Does the current in a resistor depend on the speed of electrons?

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does.

Classically, the current density in a conductor is given by $\vec j = e \vec v_D \cdot n$, where $n$ is the concentration of charge carriers, $e$ is the charge of the charge carriers and $\vec v_D$ is the drift velocity (this is part of the Drude theory). The drift velocity is the average velocity of the charge carriers, the idea is, that they are accelerated in the electric field until the collide with a an ion (or a molecule of the solvent if the conductor is an electrolyte) and therefore drift with an average velocity.

This formula, however, is not actually valid for metals as the electrons there form a degenerate Fermi gas at room temperature (and electrons move freely through a perfect crystal lattice). Therefore, only electrons with energies close to the Fermi energy contribute to the conduction process. To model this correctly one has to construct a semi-classical Boltzmann equation. The idea is to consider a space and time dependent distribution function $f_{\vec k}(\vec r, t)$, in the equilibrium, this simply reduces to the Fermi distribition $f_{\vec k}(\vec r, t) = \frac{1}{1 + \exp{(\beta \epsilon_{\vec k})}}$. Then the current is given by
$$ \vec j = e \int_{BZ} d^3k\, f_{\vec k} v_{\vec k}. $$
Where $v_{\vec k} = \nabla_{\vec k} v_{\vec k}$ is the group velocity of electrons with crystal momentum $\vec k$, the integration is over the first Brillouin zone and $f(\vec k)$ is obtained by solving the Boltzmann transport equation
$$ \partial_t f_{\vec k} + v_{\vec k} \cdot \nabla f_{\vec k} + e (\vec E + v_{\vec k} \times \vec B) \cdot \nabla_{\vec k} f_{\vec k} = \left.d_t\right|_\text{coll} f_{\vec k}, $$
where the right-hand side describes scattering mechanisms (e.g. at impurities, electron-phonon interaction or electron-electron interaction). With the correct approximations one can obtain a similar form to the classical one discussed above.